# Are there any possibilities to call some code after the Spring-WS endpoint operation result sending to the client has been finished?

Tags: java, spring, endpoint, spring-ws

We have the situation in the Spring-WS we want to perform some specific action after the sending of the data produced by the Spring-Ws-Endpoint has been finished and sent to the client.
Of course even better would be if we could call some code after the data are received by the client calling the request to our WS...

Are there any possibilities to, for example, register somewhere some callback, which would be called after the TCP connection realizing the WS-transport has been successfully closed? Of course, here could be the problem if the connections are kept alive over multiple SOAP requests, no idea it this can happen and how to prevent/evaluate it... Or any other way having similar effect we can be reasonably sure, the data have successfully arrived to the client (or at least have been sent back by the server completely)

Or, is there, at least some possibility to replace the standard spring ws http servlet connection implementation

`org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection`

by some our own implementation? Then we could override the `onClose()` method...

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-callback-example/  Can you see enableAsyncMapping like the example?

Comment: Why so specifically on the `onClose`? You can use an `EndpointInterceptor` and implement the [`afterCompletion`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/) method.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, this could be the solution, I will look into it.

Comment: @SusanMustafa Thank you, but I look the solution with Spring-WS, not JAX-WS, I am bound to the used framework

Comment: @M.Deinum Unfortunatelly, the `afterCompletion` is not suitable method - the afterComplation is called before the result is sent to the client (called from `MessageDispatcher.dispatch`, which is called from `MessageDispatcher.receive`, which is called from `WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection` and after the `MessageDispatcher.receive` is completed are the data sent back...

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring source looks like this:

`protected final void handleConnection ... {
...
  try {
   WebServiceMessage request = connection.receive(getMessageFactory());
...
   receiver.receive(messageContext);
...
    connection.send(messageContext.getResponse());
   }
  }
...
  finally {
   TransportUtils.closeConnection(connection);
   TransportContextHolder.setTransportContext(previousTransportContext);
  }
 }`
- I would need some hook after the `connection.send(messageContext.getResponse());` statement, which is not there :-(

Comment: Please don't post code as comments as that is totally unreadable. What I don't get why is that specific place to execute the code so important? What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @M.Deinum: we want to achieve the situation, we can be pretty sure the data have already been sent ot the client. the "afterCompletion" method does not offer this, it is called before the sending back to the client has been even started.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we used following solution:

1. There has been implemented the custom http connection

```
public class MyHttpServletConnection extends HttpServletConnection {

    /**
     * Constructs a new servlet connection with the given {@code HttpServletRequest} and {@code HttpServletResponse}.
     *
     * @param httpServletRequest
     * @param httpServletResponse
     */
    protected MyHttpServletConnection(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        super(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSendAfterWrite(WebServiceMessage aMessage) throws IOException {
        super.onSendAfterWrite(aMessage);
        // some specific code for notification about the send data event
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose() throws IOException {
        super.onClose();
        // some specific code for notification about the close connection event
    }
```

2. and then the default `WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` has been redefined in the following way:

```
public class MyMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        DefaultStrategiesHelper defaultStrategiesHelper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(MessageDispatcherServlet.class);
        WebServiceMessageFactory factory = defaultStrategiesHelper
                .getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class);
        setMessageFactory(factory);
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handle(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (HttpTransportConstants.METHOD_POST.equals(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
            WebServiceConnection connection = new MyHttpServletConnection(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            try {
                handleConnection(connection, (WebServiceMessageReceiver) handler);
            }
            catch (InvalidXmlException ex) {
                handleInvalidXmlException(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handler, ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            handleNonPostMethod(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handler);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3. and finally, the spring bean definitions have been extended to use `MyMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` in this way:

```
    <bean name="messageReceiverHandlerAdapter" class="somepackage.MyMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean name="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />
```

Now the own connection is used and the notifications about the data departure or connection close is performed correctly.